# Error in downloading file Ipad using Objective-c

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am new on Iphone development. I have used following code to download zip from live url in an application.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:sourceUrl];
    NSError *error=[[[NSError alloc]init] autorelease];


    NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: URL];   // Line One to download
    NSURLResponse *response1 = nil;
    NSURLRequest *theRequest =[[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60] autorelease];
    NSData* theData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response1 error:&error];   // Line two to download

    if(error != nil)
    {
        NSString *errorIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)[%d]",error.domain,error.code];        
    }
```

File is get downloaded on Iphone properly but when i am testing on IPad1 ,Ipad3 and Iphone3gs it only downloading 22kb from 6mb.

In other words downloading is not working in IPad or Iphone 3gs. It gives CFString error. Any one face same problem and any solution.

Comment: NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: URL];
This line download only few kb data. Which is not valid. Actual file size is more than 6MB

Comment: You should use a `NSURLConnection` to load your data (this will be done asynchronously).

Comment: NSURLResponse *response1 = nil;
    NSURLRequest *theRequest =[[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60] autorelease];
    NSData* theData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response1 error:&error];   // Line two to download

Here i am using NSURLConnection to download file but it doesn't work.

I have used this code from following 
https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/nsurlconnection-with-self-signed-certificates/

except certificate code

Comment: This will block your interface. I recommend you to use a asynchronous request. Btw. why are you downloading your file twice?

Comment: I was testing code. first line of code NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: URL]; is working on IPhone 4. Two time download is just for testing.

Comment: Also my requirement is to download fine Synchronously. Because after download it will extract it and i have to show user that File is downloaded.

Comment: I have also followed this link
http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/350-How-to-make-asynchronous-HTTP-requests-with-NSURLConnection